# no build output compiled for common module of Kotlin Multiplatform project

Tags: maven, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to figure out why dependent projects for my Kotlin MPP library don't see any provided modules in their `common` modules even though the targets (jvm, android) can see them.

Published via maven-publish.

The `/build` directory for the library contains nothing I can identify as an intermediate representation of my common modules, leading me to think that I need to explicitly tell Gradle to produce the files to be included as `common` in the published package.

As it is, the `.aar` and `.jar` files produced in the `android` and `desktop` (jvm) modules each look normal, but the published common module is empty.

*I need that common module to be populated before I can code against it inside the common module of dependent projects.*

Here is the relevant section of my build.gradle.kts. I omit the repository config as it appears to work.

I basically followed the instructions from [kotlinlang.org](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-publish-lib.html#avoid-duplicate-publications).

I've looked at the `maven-publish` plugin configuration, the settings for the `kotlin-multiplatformm` plugin, and the configured project structure.

kotlin version is 1.6.10, unable to update due to Jetbrains Compose dependency.

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("maven-publish")
}

kotlin {
    android {
        publishLibraryVariants = listOf("release", "debug")
    }

    jvm("desktop") {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "11"
            }
        }
    }

    val publicationsFromMainHost = listOf(jvm("desktop").name, "kotlinMultiplatform")

    publishing {
        publications {
            matching { it.name in publicationsFromMainHost }.all {
                val targetPublication = this@all
                tasks.withType<AbstractPublishToMaven>()
                    .matching { it.publication == targetPublication }
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.3.2")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.1.1")
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
                implementation("androidx.test:core:1.4.0")

                implementation("androidx.test:runner:1.4.0")
                implementation("androidx.test:rules:1.4.0")

                implementation("org.robolectric:robolectric:4.6.1")
            }
        }
        val desktopMain by getting
        val desktopTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I understand right that you have a multiplatform library and some of multiplatform apps that depends on the lib?

And app:commonMain  can't see declarations from lib:commonMain? But app:androidMain or desktopMain can? 

If it is the case then can you give their `build.gradle.kts` files? Or create some reproducer and host it on github for example.

Comment: @antoha.by the libraries are loaded from my private maven repo, the IDE can see their contents, but when I run `build`, they are not found.  A twist is that it is fixed by updating to kotlin 1.6.21.  Apparently the older version of the kotlin compiler was expecting some resource that the `maven-publish` plugin doesn't provide.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to manually supply the Kotlin stdlib dependency, rather than relying on the gradle plugin to add it.

When there are only jvm-based builds present, `commonMain` will be built with platform type of `jdk8` rather than `common`.  By making an explicit dependency on `stdlib-common`, it will be coerced back to the `common` platform, and then the correct metadata will be created and published.

```
kotlin {
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("stdlib-common"))
            }
        }
    }

}
```